Python Polars Sample N-1 by Group ID with Replacement
I am working on a bootstrapping project and need to sample M=N-1 observations with replacement where N is the number of unique observations in a specific group (defined by group_id). I need to figure out how to do this in polars. Any solutions?
Here's an example showing what I would like to accomplish:
# Have:
water_data = {
    'group_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5],
    'obs_id_within_group': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3],
    'N': [4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,3,3,3],
    'M': [3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2],
    'water_gallons': [12,23,21,11,10,10,10,23,24,25,27,30,17,12,11,14,20],
    'water_source': ['lake','lake','pond','river','lake','glacier','glacier','lake','pond','river','lake','lake','pond','river','river','lake','glacier'],
    'water_acidity': [3,4,5,1,2,4,3,2,3,3,4,6,7,8,8,3,1]
}
df=pl.DataFrame(water_data)
print(df)

# Want to randomly sample with replacement to:
sampled_water_data = {
    'group_id':            [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5],
    'obs_id_within_group': [1,2,2,3,3,3,2,4,1,1,2,1],
    'N': [4,4,4,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3],
    'M': [3,3,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2],
    'water_gallons': [12,23,23,10,10,25,24,12,27,27,14,11],
    'water_source': ['lake','lake','lake','glacier','glacier','river','pond','river','lake','lake','lake','river'],
    'water_acidity': [3,4,4,3,3,3,3,8,4,4,5,8]
}
df_sampled=pl.DataFrame(sampled_water_data)
print(df_sampled)

Not sure how to sample a specific number from each group.

Group by group_id, sample pl.len() - 1 rows with replacements, and finally explode on all columns except group_id:
df2 = (
    df.group_by("group_id")
    .agg(pl.all().sample(pl.len() - 1, with_replacement=True))
    .explode(pl.all().exclude("group_id"))
)

print(df2)

Output:
shape: (12, 7)
┌──────────┬─────────────────────┬─────┬─────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ group_id ┆ obs_id_within_group ┆ N   ┆ M   ┆ water_gallons ┆ water_source ┆ water_acidity │
│ ---      ┆ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ i64      ┆ i64                 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64           ┆ str          ┆ i64           │
╞══════════╪═════════════════════╪═════╪═════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 3        ┆ 2                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 25            ┆ river        ┆ 2             │
│ 3        ┆ 3                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 25            ┆ lake         ┆ 3             │
│ 5        ┆ 3                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 14            ┆ river        ┆ 3             │
│ 5        ┆ 3                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 14            ┆ lake         ┆ 8             │
│ 1        ┆ 2                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 21            ┆ lake         ┆ 3             │
│ 1        ┆ 2                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 12            ┆ river        ┆ 4             │
│ 1        ┆ 1                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 12            ┆ lake         ┆ 3             │
│ 4        ┆ 2                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 17            ┆ pond         ┆ 6             │
│ 4        ┆ 3                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 30            ┆ river        ┆ 7             │
│ 4        ┆ 1                   ┆ 4   ┆ 3   ┆ 12            ┆ lake         ┆ 8             │
│ 2        ┆ 2                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 10            ┆ glacier      ┆ 2             │
│ 2        ┆ 2                   ┆ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 10            ┆ lake         ┆ 3             │
└──────────┴─────────────────────┴─────┴─────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘


@user432299 Can you try adding maintain_order=True: df.group_by("group_id", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.all().sample(pl.len() - 1, with_replacement=True, seed=123))?

I got it working, thanks for the suggestion. It was working just fine, there were some deep vs shallow copy combined with sorting that was causing the issue. Thanks again!
